# Change culture for HttpResponse messages and exceptions in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, dotnet-httpclient, cultureinfo

I'm trying to have all error messages and reponses in an ASP.Net application in the english language.
This is what I tried (at the beginning of the Configure method):

```
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
        localizationOptions.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]);

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Here is the exception message that I get back (I'm using Flulrl, but using HttpClient gives same results):

```
resp = await _flurlClient
                .Request("Accounts", "Login")
                .PostJsonAsync(loginModel);

Call failed. Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione. (localhost:5001)...
```

I tried hosting both on Kestrel and IIS Express, nothing changes.
What am I missing?

Comment: did you forgot adding `services.AddLocalization();` ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I tried that but didn't help. I'm not trying to provide my own localizations. I would just like to get default errors as if I had an english localized operating system. Is this possible?

Comment: ohhh... i took a closer look and spot some... but that's quite un-fit the comment here... so take a look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

You're missing 2 part:

- Add the `services.AddLocalization();`, this will register `IStringLocalizerFactory` and the generic `IStringLocalizer` for you
- `app.UseRequestLocalization` make use of the `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>`, which you're currently missing too.

So the code should be:

```
// Registering things
services.AddLocalization();

var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US")
    };

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
    {
        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        opts.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
        Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-US"))));
    });

// Using things
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Note: As you want to only return english localization as example, I just made the config to set "en-US" would be your only choice. If you need true localization, use your own logic at `var supportedCultures` and `opts.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider`

Comment: SupportedCultures wants CultureInfos not strings, apart from that it should be working. I'll test it again tomorrow and let you know. Thanks ;D

Comment: good point... i just copy that part from your code (XD)... just fixed that part only. Have faith mah friend

Comment: I tried again but this does not work. I get this error: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione. (localhost:4545)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione.`

Comment: Here is what I do with HttpClient: `await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:4545/test");` the url is fake. I don't know whats happening, I thought it was working but it is not now... I tried both IIS Express and Kestrel

Comment: `Impossibile stabilire la connessione` this exception point out that the `httpClient` cannot call the server (the request cannot be made to server). It's not related to the localizer. By the way... this is how [my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or4kg.png) setting up... works like a charm

Comment: I am calling a non existing server on purpose, just to make it throw that exception. I want that exception to be given in english. I do not want to manually provide the translation for this exception, but I would like the program to get the translation from system libraries. Is this possible?

Comment: You startle me for a moment...put these code before your intended exception `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");` ... and even this not work... interesting... i guess i'm gonna wait for some answer too

Comment: I tried that but didn't work, I'll try again tomorrow.